# Cycles Not Rendering particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

So I've been trying to get particles into cycles, but it doesn't seem to work. First was my question about my particle system add button not showing up, but I had to scroll (facepalm). Now its probably obvious again, but I haven't figured it out. Cycles is not rendering the particles. I tried baking it, baking all dynamics, changing it to objects from halo, but it just doesn't work. The blender file is here:
[image]

Comment: Welcome stack exchange. Actually, blender does not add an object for particles by default, you have to add an object (cube, sphere, etc.) for particles under "Object" option i.e., in ParticleSetting --> Render --> Object (Dupli Object).

Comment: Thank you! Most importantly, it rendered the articles, but on the plus side, it also gives me more flexibility/control over the particles. Thanks again!